# react native app crash on some devices without error

Tags: android, react-native, nexus-10

good day everyone,

I have this react-native project where I tried to test the application throughout different devices to see how it renders.

when I tried testing it with the Nexus 10 tablet on the android emulator I faced a problem, when I click a button on the first screen of the application it just crashes and closes without any error message or red screen or anything.

I was wondering if anyone has any idea about why this is happening and if the problem is with nexus only or with the react-native itself.

thanks, everyone in advance for your time and help.

**Update**

after checking the LogCat on the android studio, those the errors i found in there. i hope this helps further explain my problem.

```
04-17 10:40:00.187 5018-5053/com.front E/unknown:ViewManager: Error while updating prop width
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value: 65
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode$MutableYogaValue.setFromDynamic(LayoutShadowNode.java:63)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setWidth(LayoutShadowNode.java:84)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-17 10:40:00.193 5018-5053/com.front E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'width' in shadow node of type: RCTView
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:116)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value: 65
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode$MutableYogaValue.setFromDynamic(LayoutShadowNode.java:63)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setWidth(LayoutShadowNode.java:84)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-17 10:40:00.204 5018-5053/com.front E/unknown:ViewManager: Error while updating prop width
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value: 65
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode$MutableYogaValue.setFromDynamic(LayoutShadowNode.java:63)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setWidth(LayoutShadowNode.java:84)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-17 10:40:00.207 5018-5053/com.front E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'width' in shadow node of type: RCTView
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:116)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value: 65
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode$MutableYogaValue.setFromDynamic(LayoutShadowNode.java:63)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setWidth(LayoutShadowNode.java:84)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-17 10:40:00.216 5018-5053/com.front E/unknown:ViewManager: Error while updating prop width
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value: 65
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode$MutableYogaValue.setFromDynamic(LayoutShadowNode.java:63)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setWidth(LayoutShadowNode.java:84)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-17 10:40:00.217 5018-5053/com.front E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'width' in shadow node of type: RCTView
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:116)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value: 65
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode$MutableYogaValue.setFromDynamic(LayoutShadowNode.java:63)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setWidth(LayoutShadowNode.java:84)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:105) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:157) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:61) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNodeImpl.updateProperties(ReactShadowNodeImpl.java:292) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:295) 
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:462) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

there was a second error but couldn't post it here due to word limit, i'll post it as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55723506/9256650).

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: sure thing but which component the one that was open or the one that didn't open ?

Comment: Do you have sms sending or call features in your app?

Comment: I assume that it is not an expo project. If correct, then I would integrate fabric's crashlytics or a similar tool in order to find what is causing the crash. Without it I think that it is going to be difficult.

Comment: are you running thru android studio?  you should be able to see console output - make sure it's showing the log for the emulator.

Comment: sorry about the late response. @MasukHelalAnik i don't have sms nor any feature just a static screen for the moment.

Comment: @Yossi it is not an expo project and i'll look into those tools.

Comment: @MikeM i'm only using the virtual device of the android studio but not the IDE and i see no errors

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown value: 65`. I know it's been super long, by my guess is you're incorrectly setting styles or props on something, maybe by passing a string to something that expects a number. I had that happen to me, and the crash only happens on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually face similar problems, But one of the things that reduce the crashes is this plugin:
https://github.com/master-atul/react-native-exception-handler.

It lets you to register a global error handler that can capture fatal/non fatal uncaught exceptions.

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it crashes on Android, you should use Android Studio to get a logcat.
The better way is implementing a crashlytics tools, I refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/)

Comment: i don't use android studio IDE due to memory limits so that would make it very hard to use. i'll try to see what to do about it

Comment: Late, but you can use the `adb logcat` command